# Move std::unique_ptr<int[]> to Platform::Collections::Vector<int>

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, c++14, move-semantics, c++-cx

I have a std::unique_ptr that points to a dynamic array. How can I instantiate a new instance of Platform::Collections::Vector by moving that array into the new Vector object? Ideally, something like this:

```
int length = 1024;
std::unique_ptr<int[]> p = std::make_unique<int[]>(length);
Vector<int>^ vec = ref new Vector<int>(std::move(p), length); // doesn't compile
```

There is a Vector constructor that moves a std::vector into it, but then I need to somehow move my unique_ptr to that std::vector. I haven't found a way to do it, should be ideally something like this:

```
int length = 1024;
std::unique_ptr<int[]> p = std::make_unique<int[]>(length);
Vector<int>^ vec = ref new Vector<int>(std::vector<int>(std::move(p), length)); // doesn't compile
```

Obviously, I don't want to copy because of performance considerations. Does anyone know a way to do it properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can move each value into the Vector element-wise (which doesn't help for int, obviously), but you can't move the allocation as a whole.

Comment: I'm actually using it with `double` and `float` so it doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Do you want the `unique_ptr` and the `Vector` to point to the same block of memory? That doesn't work because the lifetime semantics of the two are very different... the `Vector` is ref-counted across DLL boundaries whereas the `unique_ptr` lives as long as you keep the object alive in your C++ code.

Comment: Well, it works apparently with `std::vector` and `Vector` since it has a constructor taking a `std::vector` by r-value, so I thought it might work with `unique_ptr` as well.